# Why rsyslog does not write logs and the suddenly writes last X logs?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, rsyslog

I use Rsyslog as logging tool in my app. The problem is that sometimes does not write the logs and then suddenly it writes last X logs. Does anubody know why does it happen? Has somenbody experienced something like that?